# How to add SMS with specific date in android

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

Hi `stackoverflow` I'm trying to develop an application to add `SMS` to prrogrammatically, I'm using the following code to add `SMS`

```
private void addSMS()
{       
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put("address", "+91956322222");
    cv2.put("date", "1309632433677");
    cv2.put("read", 1);
    cv2.put("type", 2);
    cv2.put("body", "Hey");
    getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv2);
    cv2.clear();
}
```

Permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
```

Problem is the `Time` of the message, it's displaying the time we added the message, but not the `date` we have passed in the list of `messages`, but when I open the `message` we added then the `time` will be correct as our input, please help me to solve this riddle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem I think. Try to add this line in the end:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/-1"), null, null);
```

If you want more explanation you should [check this out!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903885/android-programatically-inserted-sms-have-incorrect-timestamp-in-messaging-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code, Thanks to @Amulya Khare

```
private void addSMS()
{       
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put("address", "+91956322222");
    cv2.put("date", "1309632433677");
    cv2.put("read", 1);
    cv2.put("type", 2);
    cv2.put("body", "Hey");
    getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv2);
    /** This is very important line to solve the problem */
    getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/-1"), null, null);
    cv2.clear();
}
```

Please follow the link to get more information [Android programatically inserted SMS have incorrect timestamp in Messaging apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903885/android-programatically-inserted-sms-have-incorrect-timestamp-in-messaging-apps)