# Android SMS Provider

Tags: java, android, date, sms, provider

I use this code to insert a new message into the sms provider:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("address", phoneNumber);
values.put("date", timer);
values.put("body", testo);
values.put("type", inbox);
values.put("read", read);
context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms"), values);
```

This works correctly when `timer` is greater than `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but when `timer` is less than `System.currentTimeMillis()`, I am finding an error. This image helps me to illustrate it:
[image]

The second message (New) came at the right time, but not the first (Old): It had to be at 8.02 and instead is at 10.04, which is the current time.

If I click on one of them and consult their details known, however, that they are correct. The second image helps me to explain.
[image]

How can I solve this problem? This appends both on android 2.3.x and on android 4.4.x.

Thank you to all.

Comment: The error is related to the date displayed in the application messages. On the right of the first image tells me that the message has arrived at 10:04 (wrong), but if I click on that message within me that is arrived at 8:02 (corrected).

Comment: just check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6903885/3326331)

Comment: What? `Sended at ??` Haha, what a grammatical mistake in the system!